# open form2 only one at a click of a button on form1

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWqrR.png)how to set a code to open form2 only one at a click of a button1 on form1. When I click on the Button1 I open my form2 and the next time I click again I open form2 again as the second same window.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying you want the button on form1 to open the same form2 object every time? If that's the case, just store your form2 object somewhere that the click event handler can access it.

Comment: When I open form2 by clicking on button1 on form2 and remaining open the next time I click on button1 on form1 to not open another window of form2 than open it to open it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you only want a single form 2 to open when you click the button even if you click it multiple times?

If so you would create a bool variable and use that to check if it is open already. So this would go inside your button clicked method.

```
if(isOpen==false)
{ 
    Application.Run(form2());
    isOpen = true;
}
```

Then once you close that form you would just change isOpen to false so you could open it up again.

Comment: That would produce an InvalidOperationException: `Starting a second message loop on a single thread in not a valid operation.  Use Form.ShowDialog instead.`

Comment: if (Application.OpenForms["Form_NAME"] == null)
{
   new Form_NAME().Show();
}